# What hops are a little less bitter than Warrior?

Tags: hops

I am using Warrior as a bittering hops in my IPA.  Looking to fine tune the recipe by lessening the bitterness a touch or two.  Can you provide me a few other hops in lesser degrees of bitterness? Thanks Q.

Answer (score 9):

Could you use less hops, or add them 10 minutes later in the boil? There are lots of hops that are less bitter (weight for weight), but whether they are a good fit depends upon the recipe.

Sorry this isn't directly answering your question, but I think you can get what you are looking for (less bitterness) without having to substitute.

Comment: I am making good beer, but still learning.  Less bitterness is the goal, I didn't know there was more then one way to get there. Thanks.

Comment: Cool. Yes, hops are pretty flexible, there's many ways to use them to get different results.

Answer (score 1):

Nugget is a little lower on the alpha side, so that may work. But I agree with mdma, adjust the amount of hops being used and/or when they are added.